# WooCommerce coupon "forcing"

Tags: php, woocommerce

Right now I'm applying 2 coupons programmatically like this:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            foreach (array_intersect(array(
                'client',
                'administrator',
                'editor'
            ), $user->roles) as $role) {
                $woocommerce->cart->add_discount(sanitize_text_field('logged_in'));
                break;
            }
        }
$number_products = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
        if ($number_products >= 3) {
            $woocommerce->cart->add_discount(sanitize_text_field('more_then_3'));
        }
```

But when a user adds a coupon that has the option "Check this box if the coupon cannot be used in conjunction with other coupons." obviously it doesn't allow me to add these coupons anymore. But I need to allow only these 2 coupons to be available to be added. I cannot uncheck the option for a user added coupon because then users will be available to add alot of them and that i cannot allow.
Any ideas how could i fix this problem?

Thanks for the help!